# looking for Bean Configuration using annotation example on Spring Integration ChannelInterceptor with patterns name

Tags: spring-integration

I implemented the ChannelInterceptor and got it working by configuring on xml. But it is not working with annotation based bean configuration.

trying to bring this to work -

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="enableLog", havingValue="true")
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns="${message.input.channel},${message.output.channel},${message.error.channel},${message.exception.channel}")
public ChannelInterceptor messageChannelInterceptor() {
    ChannelInterceptor channelInterceptor = new MessageChannelInterceptor();
    return channelInterceptor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's "not working"; the patterns? the condition?

I just wrote this test app and it works fine...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So36483811Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So36483811Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("channel", QueueChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns="*")
    public ChannelInterceptor messageChannelInterceptor() {
        ChannelInterceptor channelInterceptor = new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                System.out.println("Here: " + message);
                return message;
            }

        };
        return channelInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel channel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

}
```

and

```
Here: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=89770de1-9404-1930-283c-1d74fbb06916, timestamp=1460054756722}]
```

Comment: Let me guess! `@EnableIntegration` has been missed! :-)

Comment: Is there a way i can substitute system property value in patterns ?

Comment: I ran a test and the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that processes property placeholders (`${...}`) runs before the one that creates the interceptor. So that won't work currently. Since SpEL is evaluated later, you can use `@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns={ "#{systemProperties['foo.pattern']}", "#{systemProperties['bar.pattern']}" })`

Comment: i tried it, doesn't seem to be working.  @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns={ "#{systemProperties['message.input.channel']}", "#{systemProperties['message.output.channel']}", "#{systemProperties['message.error.channel']}" })

Comment: You specifically said `system property`. How are you setting the properties? I tested it with `-Dfoo.pattern=*`. If they are not system properties, but boot properties, use `"#{environment.getProperty('foo.pattern')}"`.

Comment: I am trying to read system-properties from jboss standalone.xml. I am able to get it working by xml configuration, but not working using annotation. this works - <int:channel-interceptor pattern="${message.input.channel},${message.output.channel},${message.error.channel}"
  ref="messageChannelInterceptor" />

Comment: `"#{environment.getProperty('foo.pattern')}"` will always work, regardless of where the properties come from (system, boot etc); if it's not working then something else is wrong and the properties are not available to the application context. There must be something else different between your XML and java configuration environments. You can use a debugger to analyze the context's `environment` property.

Comment: What if I have multiple input channels. For e.g. foo*, boo*, etc. And the number of channels is not fixed ?

As suggested [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#global-channel-configuration-interceptors), `@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns="foo*, bar*, input*")` should work. But it doesn't.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is completely inadequate. I just changed the app in my answer to `@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "chan*")` and it "works" just fine. I suggest you start a new question with your configuration and __concrete evidence__ of it "not working".